# Find the Maximum and Minimum values of $e^z$ when $z\le 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, maximum-principle

I need help finding the maximum and minimum values of $|e^z|$ on $|z|\le1$. I know we use the maximum modulus theorom but i cant seem to get an answer.

Comment: Do you mean $\max |e^z|$ on $|z|\le 1$? There are no inequalities in complex land.

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum and minimum values of $|e^z|$?  By $z \leq 1$ do you mean $\Re(z) \leq 1$?

Comment: Ted shifrin that was what i was trying to put

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(z)=e^z \ne 0$, so by the maximum principle applied to $f$ and to $1/f$, $|f|$ takes on both its maximum and its minimum on the boundary, i.e., on $|z|=1$. Since $|e^z| = e^x$ (where $z=x+iy$), the maximum value is $e$ (at $z=1$) and the minimum is $e^{-1}$ (at $z=-1$).

Comment: After "$z=x+iy$" I would have mentioned that $x$ and $y$ are real.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Well, seriously, I think everyone studying complex analysis is used to that notation.

Comment: how do you test out the points for z?

Comment: @TedShifrin : The fact that they're used to it makes it easy to write it the way you did, but I still think it's better not to do that when the material is addressed to people learning the subject.  The fact that the "reality" of $x$ and $y$ should be borne in mind bears a short reminder.

Comment: @Mandy: Where is $e^x$ largest and where is it smallest if $-1\le x\le 1$?

Comment: so do i have to do anything to e^x or could i just enter the values in to x

Comment: Do you understand why if we write $z=x+iy$ (where $x,y\in\Bbb R$) then we have $|e^z| = |e^{x+iy}| = |e^x||e^{iy}| = e^x$?

Comment: honestly no because i have an example and it comes out very different then this